# sqlserver split a string separated by commas

Tags: sql

I have a table of groups in my database(SQL server) in which I have a column of members that contains user-id's separated by commas.

What I want to do is to select all the groups that is either created by a particular user having user-id or he/she is a member of that group by checking it in the members column of a group row. my query is below but is not working I now that what I am doing is not correct please help me how should I achieve this.

```
SELECT * FROM Groups WHERE CreatedBy = @userID or Members in (@userID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `LIKE`:

Try this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Groups 
WHERE CreatedBy = @userID 
  OR Members = CONVERT(varchar(10),@userID)               ---Members only contains @userID (5)
  OR Members LIKE CONVERT(varchar(10),@userID)+',%'       ---@userID at starting (5,....)
  OR Members LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(varchar(10),@userID)+',%'  ---@userID at middle (...,5,...)
  OR Members LIKE '%,'+CONVERT(varchar(10),@userID)       ---@userID at end (...,5)
```

Comment: What if he is searches for user 10, and have only users 1,4,100,56 in the members column? your select will return the record even though it does not meet the criteria. (the downvoter is me)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Right,my friend. Edited my answer.

Comment: I've downvoted it before this edit. if this is your sql then of course there is no reason to downvote it.

Comment: yeah, sure. btw, the first condition on members should be = and not LIKE, if it's the only one in the column. (as I recall, = operator is faster then LIKE operator). I've also added that case to my answer. it turns out that when thinking together we usually come up with better answers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying that in most cases, this is a poor database design. you should, if possible, save the group members in a different table that has a foreign key to the groups table.
However, if you can't change the database design, you can try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Groups 
WHERE CreatedBy = @UserId 
OR ',' + Members + ',' LIKE '%,' cast(@UserId as varchar(10)) +',%'
```

This way you can search if the specific user is at the beginning of the list, the middle of the list or the end of the list. Also, when you are searching for user 10 you will not get user 100 by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Function and use as follows (You can simply then join change your "IN" to be the "select from function":

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN    (@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
GO
--Test
select * from fnSplit('1,22,333,444,,5555,666', ',')
select * from fnSplit('1##22#333##444','##')  --note second item has embedded #
select * from fnSplit('1 22 333 444  5555 666', ' ')
```

PFE: http://geekswithblogs.net/AngelEyes/archive/2007/04/12/111504.aspx

Comment: Shout if you still don't understand.

Comment: This is just one of many "fnSplit" functions out there.  Whatever it loses in performance, it makes up in versatility.  You are generally not working with 1000's of comma separated values (SQL Parameter limitations) AND you can also just as easily wrap that in a CTE and then use thereafter.  It will still be much quicker than a like. IMHO.

Comment: You can even use FOR XML to get the values, but the above is just much easier.  10,000+ results on Bing for "FNsplit tsql" - so many, many people use it.